# C# Checkedlistbox data binding

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkedlistbox

I have a `checkedlistBox` in C# that I am filling from sql-server.
I need to insert the checkeditems when creating a new record and I need to update the previous selected items of a certain record.

First I am trying to read the selected item of a specific record so i tried the following:

I compare the value member of every item with the list I am getting from the sql query if it matches I check the item.
So I need to use something like the value option.

```
if(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(i).**Value**

        string sql = @"select cs.id from[dbo].[Channel_availableSpecs] cas inner join[dbo].[Channel_specs] cs on cas.ChennelSpec_Id = cs.id
                where cas.Channel_Id =" + val + "order by cs.id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dta = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dta);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dta.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                 if(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(i).**Value** == dr.ToString()) checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Checked);
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

Fill `Checkedlistbox`

```
 public static void FillCheckedListox(CheckedListBox checkedListBox, string query,string displayMember, string valueMember) {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    ((ListBox)checkedListBox).DataSource = dt;
                    ((ListBox)checkedListBox).DisplayMember = displayMember;
                    ((ListBox)checkedListBox).ValueMember = valueMember;
                }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
private void selectSpecs(DataTable table)
        {
            while (checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count > 0)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices[0], false);
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            DataRow r;
            r = ((DataRowView)this.checkedListBox1.Items[i]).Row;
            string val = (r[this.checkedListBox1.ValueMember]).ToString();
            channelsSpecs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(val));
            r = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
                    foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray) if (val.ToString() == item.ToString()) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }
```